# How to stop a div becoming visible before it's content is replaced?

Tags: jquery, load, slidedown

I want to replace a div's content and then make it visible

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
$('#div01').load('about.php');
$("#div01").slideDown("slow");
});
```

But the div becomes visible before the content is changed, so user can see the previous content - which is not the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function can be used as a callback function. So the `slideDown()` only occurs when the load is complete:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $('#div01').load('about.php', function(){
        $("#div01").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $('#div01').load('about.php',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$("#div01").slideDown("slow")},100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is an ajax function so try to get it after ajax completes with `jQuery.ajaxComplete()`:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
     $('#div01').load('about.php');
});

$.ajaxComplete(function(){
   $("#div01").slideDown("slow");
});
```